# Creating new column with condition

Tags: r

I have this data set:

```
ID Type Frequency
1  A    0.136546185
2  A    0.228915663
3  B    0.006024096
4  C    0.008032129
```

I want to create a new column that change the Frequency vaules less than 0.00 in to "other" and keep other information as it is. Like this :

```
ID Type Frequency       New_Frequency
1  A    0.136546185     0.136546185  
2  A    0.228915663     0.228915663
3  B    0.006024096     other
4  C    0.008032129     other
```

I used mutate but I dont know how to keep the original frequency bigger than 0.00.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mutate()`:

```
library(dplyr)

d <- tibble(ID = 1:4,
            Type = c("A", "A", "B", "C"),
            Frequency = c(0.136546185, 0.228915663, 0.006024096, 0.008032129))

d %>%
  mutate(New_Frequency = case_when(Frequency < .01 ~ "other",
                                   TRUE ~ as.character(Frequency)))
```

Comment: Hi, what if I want to code the type that has frequency less than 0.01 as other , I mean ` type = c("A","A", "other", "other")`. how should I change the code ? Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve what you want in base r because you cannot mix characters and numerics in the same vector.  If you are willing to convert everything to characters the other answers will work.  If you want to keep them numeric you need to use NA rather than "other".  You can also try the `labelled` package which allows something like SPSS labels or SAS formats on numeric data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ifelse`

```
transform(df, Frequency = ifelse(Frequency < 0.01, 'Other', Frequency))

#  ID Type   Frequency
#1  1    A 0.136546185
#2  2    A 0.228915663
#3  3    B       Other
#4  4    C       Other
```

Note that `Frequency` column is now character since a column can have data of only one type.